# ext-http * is missing from your system, ext-mysql_xdevapi * is missing from your system

Tags: php, symfony

при попытке **composer update** вылезает следующая ошибка
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension **ext-http *** is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's http extension.
>
> Problem 2
>       - The requested PHP extension **ext-mysql_xdevapi *** is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mysql_xdevapi extension.

Но у меня уже есть в зависимостях следующие библиотеки:

**"ext-http": "*",**

**"ext-mysql_xdevapi": "*"**

В чем ошибка? Изначально пытаюсь прикрутить 
**HWIOAuthBundle**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужно установить `php-http`. Для ubuntu `sudo apt install php-http`
2. Установить `ext-mysql_xdevapi`
   https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql-xdevapi.installation.php

В композере вы прописали, но в системе то нету